# can one recite Tachanun standing?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, tachanun

If one doesn't have a chair available can one recite tachanun standing since he cant do nefillas apayim anyway sitting without a sefer torah as a yachid at home ?

Comment: I've always assumed sitting went hand-in-hand with nefilas apayim, but see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2553/6592) and [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/nefilas-apayim-in-an-area-without-a-sefer-torah/) for more discussion.

Answer (score 3):

The OU [writes](https://outorah.org/p/72383/):

> [Shulchan Aruch (OC 131:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.131.2?lang=bi) writes that the proper position for
> nefilas apayim is to be sitting. The [Mishnah Berurah (131:10)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.131.10?lang=bi)
> cites the Beis Yosef who writes this is based on Kabbalistic sources.
> However, the [Mishnah Berurah (131:38)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.131.38?lang=he-en&utm_source=outorah.org&utm_medium=sefaria_linker) notes that the Rivash
> disagrees and writes that both sitting and standing are acceptable for
> nefilas apayim. **The Mishnah Berurah concludes that in cases of
> necessity, one may rely on the Rivash and stand.** For example, if a
> person standing behind you is reciting Shemoneh Esrei and as such, it
> is not permissible to sit, Tachanun should be said with nefilas apayim
> while standing. The [Eliyah Rabbah (131:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Eliyah_Rabbah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.131.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) writes that if one is reciting Tachanun without nefilas apayim **(such as when there is no Sefer Torah), **Tacha**nun may be said sitting or standing, though the [Kaf Hachayim (131:38)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.131.38?lang=bi) is not in agreement.**

Comment: Note unquestionably the proper position for falling on ones face is fallen face down on the floor. This is all discussion of what best to do when various approximate submissive postures are impractical since even if you skip tachanun entirely you still fulfilled your obligation in shmone esrei.

Comment: How so in the Amidah? Through the forgiveness tefillah ?